# Match a numeric string from a plain text fileusing regexpi

Tags: matlab

I have. Txt file and I am looking for specific string

Example

```
Row1
Row2
Pressure      95.8
```

There could be more white-space characters between string and numbers and in every cycle there is different value: 1. Cycle 95.8>>next cycle 1009.6543>>..., but its always in this format

I tried this

```
Fid = fileread ('search.txt') 
Value = regexpi (fid, '(? <=Pressure\s*)\d*', 'match')
```

It saved just '95' instead of '95.8'

Comment: Try `regexpi (fid, '(?<=Pressure\s*)\d*(\.\d*)?', 'match')`

Answer (score 0):

To be as complete as possible, some quite generic pattern to match a double (excluding for `NaN` and `+/-Inf` cases) is the following:

```
[+\-]?(?:(?:\d+\.\d*)|(?:\.\d+)|(?:\d+))(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?
```

Quickly reviewing the pattern it says:

- Optionally the sign `+` or `-`
- Followed by (either and in order):

  - Some digits (at least one), a dot, some digits (eventually zero)
  - A dot, some digits (at least one)
  - Some digits (at least one)
- Optionally followed by:

  - The letter `e` or `E`
  - Optionally the sign `+` or `-`
  - Some digits (at least one)

The pattern to match many whitespaces (including none) is the following:

```
\s*
```

So to match the word `Pressure` followed by `many spaces` and then `a double` in the string `str`, you can use the following code:

```
function [pressures] = ParsePressures(str)
%[
    % Some default string
    if (nargin < 1)
        str = cell(0,1);
        str{end+1} = 'Row1';
        str{end+1} = 'Row2';
        str{end+1} = 'Pressure 95.8';
        str{end+1} = 'Row1';
        str{end+1} = 'Row2';
        str{end+1} = 'Pressure 1009.6543';
        str = sprintf('%s\n', str{1:end});
    end

    % Obtain 'tokens' for all macthes in 'str'
    % NB1: 'tokens' is a cell vector whose length is the number of match
    % NB2: For each match 'tokens{i}' is a cell vector containing captured groups
    tokens = regexpi(str, sprintf('%s', 'Pressure', mspaces, cdouble), 'tokens');

    % Transform maches in a array of double
    pressures = arrayfun(@(x)str2double(x{1}), tokens);
%]
end

%% --- Regular expression helpers
function [s] = mspaces()
%[
    s = '\s*'; %% This means 'as many spaces as you want'
%]
end
function [s] = cdouble()
%[
    s = '([+\-]?(?:(?:\d+\.\d*)|(?:\.\d+)|(?:\d*))(?:[eE][+\-]?\d+)?)'; %% This means 'capture a double' 
%]
end
```

It will return all pressure values in `str` as an array of double:

```
>> ParsePressures

ans =

         95.8       1009.6543
```

NB: In the code i'm using `mspaces` and `cdouble` helper functions to build the complete pattern (i.e. `sprintf('%s', 'Pressure', mspaces, cdouble)`, that is the word `Pressure`, followed by `many spaces` and followed by a `double` that I want to capture).